# Check if geo location is within radius of other geolocation without using sin/cos/tan

Tags: c, geo, geofencing

I want to develop a simple geo-fencing algorithm in C, that works without using `sin`, `cos` and `tan`. I am working with a small microcontroller, hence the restriction. I have no space left for `<math.h>`. The radius will be around 20..100m. I am not expecting super accurate results this way.

My current solution takes two coordinate sets (decimal, .00001 accuracy, but passed as a value x10^5, in order to eliminate the decimal places) and a radius (in m). When multiplying the coordinates with 0.9, they can approximately be used for a Pythagorean equation which checks, if one coordinate lies within the radius of another:

```
static int32_t
geo_convert_coordinates(int32_t coordinate)
{
     return (cordinate * 10) / 9;
}

bool                                                                             
geo_check(int32_t  lat_fixed,
          int32_t  lon_fixed,
          int32_t  lat_var,
          int32_t  lon_var,
          uint16_t radius)
{
    lat_fixed = geo_convert_distance(lat_fixed);
    lon_fixed = geo_convert_distance(lon_fixed);
    lat_var   = geo_convert_distance(lat_var);
    lon_var   = geo_convert_distance(lon_var);

    if (((lat_var - lat_fixed) * (lat_var - lat_fixed) + (lon_var - lon_fixed) * (lon_var - lon_fixed))
        <= (radius * radius))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This solution works quite well for the equator, but when changing the latitude, this becomes increasingly inaccurate, at 70°N the deviation is around 50%. I could change the factor depending on the latitude, but I am not happy with this solution.

Is there a better way to do this calculation? Any help is very much appreciated. Best regards!

UPDATE

I used the input I got and managed to implement a decent solution. I used only signed ints, no floats.

The haversine formula could be simplified: due to the relevant radii (50-500m), the deltas of the latitude and longitude are very small (<0.02°). This means, that the sine can be simplified to `sin(x) = x` and also the arcsine to `asin(x) = x`. This approach is very accurate for angles <10° and even better for the small angles used here. This leaves the cosine, which I implemented according to @meaning-matters 's suggestion. The cosine will take an angle and return the actual result multiplied by 100, in order to be able to use `int`s. The square root was implemented with an iterative loop (I cannot find the so post anymore). The haversine calculation was done with the inputs multiplied by powers of 10 in order to achieve accuracy and afterwards divided by the necessary power of 10.

For my 8bit system, this caused a memory usage of around 2000-2500 Bytes.

Comment: For 90°N, what is the value of  `lat_fixed`?

Comment: It would be 90(.)00000 = 90x10^5

Comment: "This solution works quite well for the equator" yet even with latitude == 0, `(lon_var - lon_fixed) * (lon_var - lon_fixed)` can overflow 32-bit math.  Rather than scale by 100,000, perhaps scale by 100 - or use wider than 32-bit math. OTOH, perhaps you have an _unstated_ limit of the magnitude of `lon_var - lon_fixed`?

Comment: I am think of a solution, akin to @meaning-matters that uses the [chord length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#From_chord_length).

Comment: You need to implement the equation in checks and consider the maximum/minimum values allowed at each step. If you are using a 32 bit MCU then maybe also consider 64 bit arithmetic, since it doesn't give that much overhead. (If you are using something smaller than 32 bit then your project is likely toasted, as per design...) What exactly is "a small microcontroller"?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica good catch, the functions are missing validity checks entirely, I omitted them for a simple example of my approach. Thanks for suggesting chord length, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Lundin I am using an 8-bit controller ;) I hope, that int32 won't limit my calculations. As I am only checking small radii, I could do a rough check for the coordinates (e.g. max 2deg difference) before doing the acutal calculation

Comment: A pre-check (I suspect no squaring is needed there) makes most sense to not have to change scaling.  BTW, are your `int/unsigned` 16-bit.  (Affects `radius * radius`)?

Comment: I agree. Yes, they are in the example code. In the actual code I had a check, that limited the radius to 100, so no overflow could occur.

Comment: @earthling Your project is toast then, you picked the wrong MCU for the task. Disassemble this code for your target and see what a horrible mess it creates for machine code. Please trust me on this, I've done really stupid things like PID controllers and even signal processing on old 8-bitters. It's stupid self-torture, go with a 32 bit Cortex M. In this case maybe even M4 or larger so you can get a FPU - which will remove your "cant use math.h" head ache.

Comment: @Lundin I really appreciate your heads-up, sadly I am restricted, I have literally no other choice over the controller. As always, this is a new, unforeseen requirement ;) The good thing is, that the check occurs rarely and doesn't need to be quick. In terms of memory usage I will for now hope for the best and report  back with the memory usage once I implemented meaning-matters' solution.

Comment: Ok well maybe you can salvage the situation by dividing 100 meters or whatever human-suitable unit you have, into 65536 steps. Then do all arithmetic on "steps" not on meters. But why can't you change MCU? Have you already bought some expensive tool chain or manufactured a big batch of PCBs?

Comment: @Lundin: I don't quite understand your suggestion. I can't change the MCU, because this feature is supposed to be added to an existing product, which already exists. So really no options here. I  updated my question with my solution. I am quite happy with it, however, in the end, the memory usage is too high, it almost brings the mcu to 100% rom usage. Maybe in the future the mcu will be upgraded, then this function can be enabled. And a big thanks to you in particular, I think you helped me on every question I posted on so :) thanks a lot. And I get your heads-up!! really messy with the ints

Comment: Maybe whatever 8 bit MCU you are using got a "big brother" in the same family, code & pin compatible but with more flash and RAM?

Comment: Yes, luckily there is one more with double the rom/ram and it also has the same dimensions. This will likely be changed in the future but this is not up to me ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the [Havesine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) function using your own trigonometric functions that use lookup tables and do interpolation.

Because you don't want very accurate results, small lookup tables, of perhaps twenty points, would be sufficient.  And, simple linear interpolation would also be fine.

In case you don't have much memory space: Bear in mind that to implement sine and cosine, you only need one lookup table for 90 degrees of either function.  All values can then be determined by mirroring and offsetting.

Comment: I really like this approach. Doing a lookup table + interpolation for sin and cos is very small, I think 20 points would be plenty sufficient. I'll try this and report back

Comment: @earthling Good to hear it all worked out!  Nice `sin()` `asin()` simplification.